# Get data from URL in Angular 5

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I enter a link in url bar.

```
http://localhost:4200/reset-password-action/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9/5
```

I want to get **eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9** and **5** from url.

I have it in my **app-routing.module.ts** file.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'reset-password-action/:token/:user_id', component: NewPasswordComponent }
];
```

I need a simple syntax to get this data.

Comment: *Where* do you want to get this data?

Comment: for now in the current component **NewPasswordComponent**

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#extract-the-id-route-parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all Where do you want to get this data?
**If you want it in the same component, in your case I think it is NewPasswordComponent**

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class NewPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.token);
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.user_id);
  } 
}
```

OR You can get like below also:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe(event => {
      this.token = event.token;
      this.user_id = event.user_id;
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import activated route first then use this

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
class ABC {
    id: any;
    token: any;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
            if (typeof params['id'] !== 'undefined') {
                this.id = params['id'];
            } else {
                this.id = '';
            }
            if (typeof params['token'] !== 'undefined') {
                this.id = params['token'];
            } else {
                this.id = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get query params like this using ActivatedRoute. Here is the example::

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 queryParamsStatus ='';

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.queryParamsStatus= params['status'];
        console.log(queryParamsStatus );

      });
    let tempRows = this.rows.filter(s => s.staus === this.queryParamsStatus);
  }

}
```

You can get token/userId by simply replacing status by token or userid.

Hope this will work.